# Use of conditional operator

Tags: c#

I have a table in my database which separates the address into three columns:

```
First = The House number and street name NOT NULL
Middle = e.g Business park name or NULL 
Last = Area name or NULL
```

The `First` column will always have a value but the other two may contain a value. What I'm trying to achieve is if `Middle or Last` is null return the `First` column value If `First or Middle` have value then return those two and if all then return all 3 of them. So I thought of using The conditional operator to achieve this.

My code is as follows:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
   return dbContext.User.Select(a => new MyUserDto
   {
      Address = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.First + a.Middle + a.Last) ? a.First + a.Middle + a.Last : a.First 
   }).ToList();
}
```

How can change the code to get the value of `First and Middle` if middle is not null

or should I create separate properties in my `MyUserDto` to represent what's in the database?

Comment: I would make your DTO match the database table exactly, it helps when you are going the other way, inserting the DTO into the table, you don't have to try to parse things out to get the address as it was entered.

Comment: You shouldn't need to - concatenating `null` onto a string does not return null, it returns the original string.  e.g. `"Test" + null == "Test"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if Middle or Last is null return the First column value If First or Middle have value then return those two and if all then return all 3 of them

If I interpret your requirements *literally* then it would be

```
Address = a.First + (a.Middle == null || + a.Last == null) ? "" : a.Middle + a.Last;
```

But that would mean if `Last` is null but `Middle` is not then the value for `Last` is ignored, which seems odd.  I suspect you just want blank strings in place of *any* null which would just be

```
Address = a.First + a.Middle + a.Last;
```

Since null strings are treated like empty strings in .NET when concatenating them with non-null strings (unlike SQL).

> or should I create separate properties in my MyUserDto to represent what's in the database?

You certainly can do that, and just add a property that does the concatenation on the fly.  That way, you can set the parts independently without having to parse a concatenated string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I highly appreciate it. I will accept this as soon as the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

```
Address = a.First + a.Middle + a.Last
```

This should work for you